# Ошибка could not convert string to float:

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При обучении модели возникает ошибка

Исходный код:

## Обучение моделей и вывод показателей качества

for model in models:
# Обучение модели
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Предсказание на тестовой выборке
y_pred = model.predict(X_test.values) if model.**class**.**name** == 'KNeighborsClassifier' else model.predict(X_test)

```
# Сохранение результатов в словарь
model_results['Model'].append(model.__class__.__name__)
model_results['Accuracy'].append(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
model_results['Precision'].append(precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro'))
model_results['Recall'].append(recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro'))
model_results['F1 Score'].append(f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro'))

# Вывод покахзателей качества
print(f"{model.__class__.__name__}: Общая точность: {accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred):.2f}")
print(f"Точность предсказания по классам: {precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average=None)}")
print(f"Полнота предсказания по классам: {recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average=None)}")
print(f"F1 Score: {f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average=None)}\n")
```

**Выдает ошибку:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Nurse'**

Что из себя представляет датасет - прикрепляю к вопросу.

Как можно исправить эту ошибку? Спасибо!